# Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultreference' in jackson for composite key

Tags: java, jackson, javers

Recently i got this error,

> can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultreference' in jackson for composite key

I googled alot but found the below option to use,

> JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference

[Reference](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences)

But my situation is,

```
Class Parent{
private int id;
@JsonManagedReference
Set<Child> childSet;
}

Class Child{
 private ChildId childId;
 private String name;
 }

 Class ChildId{
 private int childKey;
 @JsonBackReference 
 private Parent parent;
 }
```

As you see, in the child class it has a composite key. I can not change this since it has relationship with DB.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Note:
I'm using Jackson 2.4.3
I'm using Javers 1.2.9 for Object comparison

Update1:

As per suggestion, I have removed JsonManaged and JsonBack reference annotations and added JsonIgnore to Parent attribute in childId Class.
But im getting below error with Javers,

> JaVers runtime error - diff for Set of ValueObjects is not supported

Comment: Guys...Any suggestion plz?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is resolved.
The most weird way of solving.. ;)

Removed `@JsonManagedReference` in Parent.

Add `@JsonBackReference` in Parent object which is in Child's Id object.

Ex:

```
Class Parent{
  private int id;
  Set<Child> childSet;
}

Class Child{
  private ChildId childId;
  private String name;
}

Class ChildId{
  private int childKey;
  @JsonBackReference 
  private Parent parent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, searching the whole web, this was the only answer that worked!

Comment: You Welcome @rfsbsb

Answer (score 0):

Do you see this exception on deserializing JSON to Java objects?

If yes, the workaround that I used was to - 
1. Remove the @JsonManagedReference and  @JsonBackReference from the entities. 
2. @JsonIgnore the Parent reference (for ex, in your ChildId class). So parent reference in ChildId is null on serializing.
3. To deserialize, send two seperate entities (Child and Parent) back to the service. Once both the objects are available, I set the Parent back into the ChildId class which helps to satisfy the circular reference.

Comment: Hi Kamlesh, Thank you so much for your reply. After did the modification I got below error,
11:39:59,712 ERROR SetChangeAppender:46 - could not diff Field Set<ChildObj> Child1; //declared in: Parent, JaVers runtime error - diff for Set of ValueObjects is not supported

Comment: Well you're doing manual what annotations can do automaticaly for you :)